# Reading JSON data variable

Tags: php, json

Im having a problem reading JSON data. It is probably just a simple thing, but I dont know how to solve it. Basically I have a PHP page, which reads JSON data from a url. 
It all works fine except for one variable. The problem with this variable is, that the actual name of the node in the JSON file contains a number and this causes an error in the php file, which stops executing.
The variables that work are for example like this:

```
$name = $data->name;
```

The one that doesnt work is:

```
$rain = $data->rain->3h;
```

When I do this I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in...
```

When I remove that "3" and leave it just like "h", it works ok, but the problem is, that the node is called "3h", therefore it works, but it doesnt load the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these methods:

1. [`json_decode(,true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

   Now you can access the JSON as a multidimensional array such as:
   `$data['rain']['3h']`
2. [`$data->rain->{'3h'}`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
3. `$data->rain['3h']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "3h" with quotes?

Comment: yes, that doesnt help either because it then probably wants to assign "3h" instead of reading it, either way, this doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Use curly brackets like this:

```
$rain = $data->rain->{3h};
```